# {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":83,"result":"0x0"}

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

if my geth is syncing in fast mode and I try to query method eth_blockNumber, will it throw me an error, cause it is not, i tried curl in verbose mode and below is the result.

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8545 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8545
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 69
> 
* upload completely sent off: 69 out of 69 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Vary: Origin
< Date: Mon, 13 Jul 2020 13:05:50 GMT
< Content-Length: 41
```

Can anyone help me with this doubt?

Comment: actually this is throwing error for each and every method now, but at the same time geth is syncing in full power.

Comment: What is your curl command ? Has your node finished to synchronize ? What are you querying ?

Comment: This is my curl command 

curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8545/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
 "jsonrpc":"2.0",
 "method":"eth_blockNumber",
 "params":[],
 "id":83
}'

No it is still synchronising, and I'm asking for the blockNumber whatever is the latest with geth

Comment: has anyone face such issue before, if yes then can you please tell me how you resolved it

Comment: I do not get it. You are asking us to test something for you. Can't you just do it yourself ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain please read the query, I have tested this and it is not throwing me any error but instead it shows this {“jsonrpc”:“2.0”,“id”:83,“result”:“0x0”}, that's why I reached out to the community to confirm if any of you have faced this thing, if so then how did you resolve.

Comment: Check the documentation. It says it all: https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_blocknumber